# SWF file not launching in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, flash, firefox, safari

I have 10 html files, essentially they are quizzes that end users can open in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on both Macs and PCs.

These files were originally created about 3 years ago and now I'm finding that the latest versions of Chrome and Safari will not open on a Mac, not sure about PCs.

From my very limited knowledge about coding, these html files should be launching a `.swf` file that plays in the browser. Is this something that is easily fixable?

Comment: Since you're asking on a **programming** forum, how about showing the code for embedding the swf? Or at least a link to one of your html & swf for testing... Are your swf running from `https` location?

Comment: here is a link to one of them:

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/oj4e9lotjxb730tk3xyzlhq8t0ygyl7i

Comment: I noticed Chrome (Windows PC) loads the swf files (quiz, data and frame) but it hangs on _frame.swf_ which has a related _frame.xml_, I wonder if it's seen as a security issue for browser content to load XML files from a user's hard drive?... I'll test within 24 hrs. Does the quiz work online at least (especially from `https://` location)?

Comment: My end users are not doing the quizzes online, they simply download the zip, unzip, and take the quiz. Basically they are doing these locally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your version of the Flash plug-in? If .swf files aren't playing that could be the culprit, it could also be a setting where Flash is disabled in your browser.

Comment: Yes, flash has been updated. here's a link to one of the quizzes: https://app.box.com/s/oj4e9lotjxb730tk3xyzlhq8t0ygyl7i

Comment: It seemed to be loading for me, I didn't wait for the quiz to load but I could see that it opened the flash file.

Comment: thanks for checking! all 10 seem to open on a Mac using Firefox only, it's Chrome and Safari that won't load it.

Comment: and just to clarify, it's only the 'quiz_html5.html' that will open, the other 2, 'quiz.html' and 'quiz_unsupported.html', do not open

Comment: @sjsf2017 that _quiz_unsupported.html_ should work in all browsers since it only contains one sentence of text (with link)... I believe Firefox is still using the older NPAPI format of plugins whilst Chrome now uses their own PPAPI (now even used by Safari & Edge too). Supposedly safer than NPAPI but yet seems to break the working of Flash Player plugin with some SWF files.

Comment: quiz_unsupported did not work for me on Mac but I'll try it again.

Comment: @VC.One On a Mac, all 3 browsers load this:

Comment: Unsupported Browser

The HTML5 player does not currently support this web browser.

Click here to view this project using the standard Flash player.

Comment: after 'click(ing) here', the .swf does not load

Comment: The only file of the 3 that work on a Mac, is 'quiz_html5.html' using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

> *"My end users are not doing the quizzes online, they simply download the zip, unzip, and take the quiz. Basically they are doing these
>   locally"*

If you're willing to skip using Flash Player (the browser plugin) and just run Flash Player as a desktop application then it will run your Quiz fine.

I working am on a Windows PC. The *FlashPlayer.exe* should already exist on your device (ie: the browser runs it within web pages as a "plugin").

Any SWF can be right-clicked in file explorer then choose *"Open with Flash Player"*. Maybe package such free stand-alone players in some folder with your Quiz?

[image]

Edit:

> *"So would you recommend having a separate package for each quiz? One for Windows and one for Mac?... Finally, by adding the stand alone
>   player, how would the .swf file know to use the player, instead of the
>   default .swf player on the end users computer?"*

Here is the link for standalone FlashPlayers (called **Projectors**) from Adobe. The Projector is also a window like in picture above. Visually there is no difference between versions **installer** & **standalone**, except the **installer** version becomes known to other apps of your OS (*eg:* browsers)

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

PC (exe) : [**Download the Flash Player projector**](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/24/flashplayer_24_sa.exe)

MAC (dmg) : [**Download the Flash Player projector**](https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/24/flashplayer_24_sa.dmg)

(no installation, just download and run the **.exe** / **.dmg** file). Drag swf file into the window. Test this for both operating systems.

Once tested, then decide on instructions for end-users. Apparently they can't be privately distributed (see note below), so on your site maybe offer separate links for both quiz & these player downloads.

**1)** Either inform users to run the downloaded standalone player & drag Quiz swf into player window when it shows.

**2)** Or try making some script/batch file. For example to test now on PC just put standalone player into same location as `Quiz.swf`. Now open **NotePad** program paste this text :

```
start flashplayer_24_sa.exe quiz.swf
```

Save as *`StartQuiz.bat`* in same location as `Quiz.swf`. Now test by double-clicking *`StartQuiz.bat`* to see it all run automatically. Research the MAC/OSx equivalent of such a script file.

**note** about distribution : Check with them if it's okay to package... Adobe says these are for testing by devs only & must not be distributed to general public. I think their logic (or fear?) is that if too many standalone player links are out there, the average web users might get the wrong version & won't understand when it's not showing within browsers etc.

Comment: So would you recommend having a separate package for each quiz? One for Windows and one for Mac?  And, can you recommend a stand alone player similar to Media Player Classic H.C but for Mac?  Finally, by adding the stand alone player, how would the .swf file know to use the player, instead of the default .swf player on the end users computer?

Comment: @VC, Is "Open with Flash Player" safe?